# Multiprocessing Python 3

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pickle, python-camelot

I have been trying to create a multiprocessing pool for a series of task on python 3. The tasks are as follows:
1. Reading through the pdf files and capturing tables in the pdf file followed by-
2. Creating a pickle file to store the table objects 
3. Loading the pickle files

I ran the python code in serializing as well as parallelizing mode on three pdf files for testing purposes. Sequencing is running the entire process in 200 seconds and creating pickle files in the working directory. However, multiprocessing isn't generating the pickle files in the directory but it's taking 39 seconds to run the process.

The code for sequencing can be found below:

```
os.chdir('C:/Users/dir_path')

    def process_table(pdf):
        for pdf in pdfs:
            tables = camelot.read_pdf(pdf, pages = 'all', flag_size=True, copy_text=['v'], line_scale=40) 
            print(f'Process {os.getpid()} Processing File Name:{pdf}\nTotal Tables found:{len(tables)}')
            with open(pdf.split('.pdf')[0] + '.pkl', 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump(tables, f)
                print(f'Process {os.getpid()} Pickle file created for: {pdf}')
            with open(pdf.split('.pdf')[0] + '.pkl', 'rb') as g:
                pickle.load(g)
                print(f'Process {os.getpid()} Pickle file loaded: {pdf}')

    def process_handler():    
        start_time = time.time()
        pdfs = [file_name for file_name in os.listdir()]
        process_table(pdfs)
        end = time.time()
        duration = round(time.time() - start_time)
        print(f'Whole Process completed in {duration} second(s)') 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_handler()
```

The output of the code is below:

[Output of Serialising](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnYUu.png) 
The code for multiprocessing is below:

```
os.chdir('C:/Users/dir_path')

def process_table(pdf):
        tables = camelot.read_pdf(pdf, pages = 'all', flag_size=True, copy_text=['v'], line_scale=40) 
        print(f'Process {os.getpid()} Processing File Name:{pdf}\nTotal Tables found:{len(tables)}')
        with open(pdf.split('.pdf')[0] + '.pkl', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(tables, f)
            print(f'Process {os.getpid()} Pickle file created for: {pdf}')
        with open(pdf.split('.pdf')[0] + '.pkl', 'rb') as g:
            pickle.load(g)
            print(f'Process {os.getpid()} Pickle file loaded for: {pdf}')

def process_handler():    
    start_time = time.time()

    files = [file_name for file_name in os.listdir()]
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(process_table, files)

    duration = round(time.time() - start_time)
    print(f'Whole Process completed in {duration} second(s)') 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_handler()
```

I would really appreciate your valuable feedback on this. This is crucial because sometimes the 20 MB pdf file takes very long to get converted to pickle file with table objects stored in them. Hence, the process is stuck on first job (i.e. pdf of size 20 MB) and cannot move to the next job until first one finishes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A few items;

- I've only used the multiprocessing Pool which I've found works reasonably well.
- `process_table` is being called with `pdfs`, outside of the map function, so is processing in serial.
- `work_items` does not contain anything as far as I can tell, apart from None.
- You call `process_table` with a list argument (`pdf`), but then use the global `pdfs` variable.

I'd suggest something like;

```
import multiprocessing as mp

files = [file_name for file_name in os.listdir()]
with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()-1) as pool:
    pool.map(files, process_table)
```

Comment: I tried the method that you suggested but seems like jupyter notebook hungs and I had to manually interrupt the code processing. Instead I tried the below code chunk: `files = [file_name for file_name in os.listdir()]
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(process_table, files)` The code takes 22 seconds to complete the process which is almost 1/10th the time it was taking in serializing. However, I don't see the pickle files created and saved in my working directory

Comment: @Nipun Don't forget to also remove the iteration on ```pdfs``` in ```process_table```. I can't see why it wouldn't write anything - check the paths that you think it's writing to. Do you get any output from the print statements?

Comment: There is just one output after running the code which is : 'Whole Process completed in 39 second(s)'. Apart from this, it doesn't print other statements and neither it is creating pickle files in the working directory. I have updated my code per your suggestions and I see the processing time decreased to 39 seconds now. I am not sure why it showed me 22 seconds yesterday. I have edited my above post and included the updated code now

Comment: @Nipun, the code you posted doesn't quite work, but looks like with ThreadPoolExecutor you have to consume the results from the iterable otherwise it doesn't do anything; so ```for r in executor.map(process_table, pdfs): print(r)```

Comment: Thanks for the another update! I did try this and got the ghostscript error. One thing I forgot to mention is that camelot has dependency on ghostscript, so ghostscript.exe file needs to be activated at the back while running the multiprocessing code. Do you think dependency of the code on another tool could be the reason that multiprocessing code is not working?

Comment: @Nipun, yes, I think it won't allow. Would suggest using bash instead with the ```subprocess``` which will start multiple ghostscript instances. See github references; https://github.com/atlanhq/camelot/issues/347

Comment: Thank you very much for your timely and useful updates. The link that you shared is definitely going to help me to explore this issue in depth.